# PHP decodes the ajax sent variable wrong

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, post

I try to send a variable using jquery and ajax to php script. Then I want to use that variable in creating a file name but it fails. The file name is always "0" and does not locate at the dir "redirect".

Here is the code:

Ajax:

```
    var pageName=$('#movie').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "phpstuff.php",
        data: { pageName: 'pageName'},
        cache: false,
        success: function()
            {
                alert(pageName);
            }
    });
```

the "pageName" variable gets the value from an input box with an id "movie"

The php file

```
function createPage ($newPage){

$file=fopen("redirect/"+$newPage+".php","w") or exit("Fail to create the page");
$data = "some text I want to be in a file";
fwrite ($file, $data);
fclose($file);
}

$newPage = $_POST["pageName"];
createPage($newPage);
```

I have searched the net for hours and still can't fix the problem.

Comment: Can you echo `$_POST["pageName"]` and post the result.

Comment: you look like you are trying to send json data
for pure html data try this: 
data:"pageName=pageName",

Comment: @andrew JSON is a valid argument to `data`.

Comment: @Waleed Khan yes json is valid but like the OP uses it in his function (simple html post data and not json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatenation should be done with `.`:

```
"redirect/" . $newPage . ".php"
```

Comment: How stupid of me, thank you, now it worked :D I was going crazy already.

Answer (score 4):

Line

```
data: { pageName: 'pageName'},
```

should be

```
data: { pageName: pageName},
```

A print_r( $_POST["pageName"] ) would show you what is being passed, in the first version $_POST["pageName"] is 'pageName'

You could also use

```
data: 'pageName='+pageName,
```

The description on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for data parameter is'nt very clear as it talks about GET and dosn't mention POST.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to send the correct value of pageName

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
$file=fopen("redirect/"+$newPage+".php","w") or exit("Fail to create the page");
```

to

```
$file=fopen("redirect/".$newPage.".php","w") or exit("Fail to create the page");
```

Notice the changes from `+` to `.`. In PHP `+` is for addition, and `.` is for string concatenation.